# Looping GroupBy in Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a dataframe that has multiple `Activity` for a given `Event` like so:

```
+-------+--------+
|  Event|Activity|
+-------+--------+
|2646922|   15400|
|2646922|   15399|
|2646922|   90664|
|2646922|   11512|
+-------+--------+
```

And each `Activity` has multiple `RESULT` values like so:

```
+-------+--------+------+
|  Event|Activity|RESULT|
+-------+--------+------+
|2646922|   15400| 399.9|
|2646922|   15400| 400.1|
|2646922|   15400|   400|
|2646922|   15400|400.03|
|2646922|   15400|399.93|
|2646922|   15400| 400.1|
|2646922|   15400|399.99|
|2646922|   15400| 400.1|
|2646922|   15400|   400|
|2646922|   15400| 400.1|
|2646922|   15400| 400.1|
|2646922|   15400| 400.1|
|2646922|   15400|399.91|
|2646922|   15400|   400|
|2646922|   15400|400.13|
|2646922|   15400| 400.2|
|2646922|   15400|399.92|
|2646922|   15400|   400|
|2646922|   15400|400.28|
|2646922|   15400| 399.3|
+-------+--------+------+
```

I want to groupby `Event` and cycle aggregations through `Activity`.
For example, I want to find the mean of `RESULT` in Activities `15399, 90664, 11512` in the `Event=2646922` without `Activity=15400`.
Then find the mean of `RESULT` in Activities `15400, 90664, 11512` without `Activity=15399` and so on.

Typically in Python we would use a for loop for each Event.
Is there an efficient way to do this in PySpark? Would I have to use a Dictionary or Tuples?

Would appreciate any insight.
Thank You

Comment: Why not filter before grouping?

Comment: you cannot manupulate directly the data in your dataframe with python. If you want to use python, then you need to `collect`your data. otherwise, you're stuck with spark, and you have to use the builtin functions which are set programming, not iterative programming.

Comment: @Steven Yes I would like to leverage the distributed computing power of spark without having to use collect.

Comment: @ernest_k You mean filter based on all the Event-Activity combinations and then group it? If so how would I get the aggregation for each event-activity combo without having to manually specify it?

Comment: according to your example, you have 2 dataframes ? or one big dataframe ?

Comment: @Steven its one big dataframe, I showed the distinct activities for each event for ease of asking my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming `df` is your dataframe.

> I want to find the mean of RESULT in Activities 15399, 90664, 11512 in the Event=2646922 without Activity=15400

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df.where(
    "Event=2646922 and Activities in (15399, 90664, 11512)"
).groupBy("Event").agg(F.mean("RESULT"))
```

> find the mean of RESULT in Activities 15400, 90664, 11512 without Activity=15399

```py
df.where(
    "Event=2646922 and Activities in (15400, 90664, 11512)"
).groupBy("Event").agg(F.mean("RESULT"))
```

If you want to exclude each activity number one after the other, you need to create a cartesion join with condition `left.event = right.event and left.activities != right.activites`. Therefore, you will have for each activity number, all the RESULT of the other activities, and you can perform a simple group by.

---

If I use your sample dataframes, the first one is `df1` and the second one `df2`. As you said it is one big dataframe, you should apply distinct to create `df1` and the apply my code.

```py
df1.join(
    df2, on="event"
).where(
    df1.activities != df2.activities
).groupBy("Event", df1.activities).agg(F.avg("result"))
```

Comment: I have about 10k events with each event having about 20 activities. So I have a total of 200k event-activity combos. I would not be able to manually specify the activity numbers in the `where` clauses. I reduced the number of activities to 4 in my example to simplify the question. I was thinking of identifying the Activities within each event and then cycling through them with a lambda function? Is that even possible?

Comment: @thentangler Then, you should apply the last paragraf

Comment: @thentangler As you said it is one big dataframe, you should apply distinct to create `df1` and then, apply my code.

Comment: Yes, I can split the dataframe into the two and apply the method you described. Let me try that.

Comment: I get an empty dataframe :(
Is it because `df1.Activity != df2.Activity` in the `where` clause does not pick up anything? Because all the Activities in df1 are present in df2 so the `where` clause is always false?

Comment: @thentangler Sorry, I made a typo in my code. Fixed it. The join condition is on event, not activity

Comment: I'm still getting an empty dataframe. The join shows data, but it is failing at the where clause.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223041/discussion-between-steven-and-thentangler).

Comment: I figured out the issue. It was due to pyspark not knowing which df.column to compare to since they were the same name. I simply changed the `Activity` column in `df1` to `df1.Act` and it works now. So thank you! This solution works for me!